# Delay when using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier but not performSegueWithIdentifier?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

The code below is used to push another view controller onto the navigation stack.

When using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, the segue is noticeably sluggish the first time (~3 seconds) but occurs reasonably fast each subsequent time. Other SO posts suggested ensuring the segue occurs on the main thread, which the code accomplishes, but this didn't fix the problem.

However, using `performSegueWithIdentifier` causes no delay.

The `viewDidLoad` code for `SendViewController` is the same for the first and subsequent pushes.

Tried blanking out `viewDidLoad` for the destination view controller, but still the lag exists for `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` but not for `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

How to fix the delay with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`?

No delay:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier(SendSegue, sender: self)  
}
```

Results in delay when showing SendViewController for first time:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(self.SendViewControllerID) as! SendViewController
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }   
}
```

Comment: What exactly is going on in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear methods of destination view controller?

Comment: @arturdev there is no overriding of viewWillAppear. in viewDidLoad there is just setting of delegates and hiding/showing UI elements, and more importantly the code is the same every time (i.e., no difference between first and subsequent showings). any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any network request there? Or any `[UIImage imageNamed:]` call?

Comment: @arturdev no network calls, and no UIImage calls. thanks for your help!

Comment: Then try to remove ALL actions from that button, and connect again. 
I know that it's very strange, but sometime it works for me :)

Comment: @arturdev ok will try it, may help to focus on problem.

Comment: @arturdev unfortunately that didn't help. even created a second button to initiate the segue, but the performance is the same.

Comment: @arturdev updated the question with more info

Comment: @Crashalot try isolating your issue. create a sample project and check if the delay still occurs.

Comment: I created my own sample project for this issue but couldn't observe any significant performance difference.  If you haven't already, you may want to test it on a device, not just the simulator, just in case it's a simulator problem.  If you are still getting the problem, I would create a separate git branch or duplicate your project and start stripping out everything in your project that isn't necessary for replicating the problem.  Upload a sample project of the minimum amount of code required that still has this problem.

Comment: OK thanks @ChristopherWhidden will try and report back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was isolated to the presence of a UITextField in the destination view controller, that is, removing the UITextField removes the lag.

Then it was further isolated to the presence of a custom font.

In other words, using the system font on the UITextField, rather than a custom font, removes the lag. No explanation why, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

This issue could occur in many different scenarios. The best way determine what is causing your specific problem is by profiling with the instruments included in Xcode.

1. Click and hold the **Build button** in your xcode window. You will see four options appear, select **Profile**.
2. Once the build runs a window with instruments will pop up. Select, **Time Profiling** from the options.
3. A new window will appear with various metrics in it. The top left corner will have a **red record button**. Click the red record button and this will launch the app on your phone.
4. Proceed to the transition giving you problems. End the recording after the transition occurs by selecting the same button you started the recording with.
5. Review the *"Details"* pane in the bottom left corner. You will see a column titled *"Running time"* that shows the time it took to execute every method in your code (both OS methods and user generated code)
6. Determine if anything is out of place or occurs that is not intended. Possibly go back and execute the transition again to compare the difference between the two. Clicking the function in the list will take you directly to the code being executed. This can be very helpful.

It is very likely that if a transition takes 3-5 seconds one particular function will be obvious when following these steps. Happy profiling!

WWDC from last year has a great segment on this as well. Def worth checking out here: (open in Safari only) [WWDC Profiling Talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/412/)

Comment: great idea, and thanks for the detailed instructions! just upvoted so now you almost doubled SO rep. :)

Comment: Thanks! If you feel this was the best answer please annotate it as such to let others know it worked for you :)

Comment: Unfortunately it wasn't very helpful for this problem, but it surely will help in the future. Still don't know where the problem lies as the profiler isn't highlighting any obvious problems in code. Updated the question with more details in case you can help.

Comment: do you know how you would configure the profiler to show how much time was spent inside a particular view controller?

Answer (score 0):

After time profiling I realized it was the call to `instantiateViewController` which I couldn't find anything that could help me with that.

Unfortunately, the only thing that worked was either using a separate storyboard for that view controller and instantiating it from there, or redoing the view controller programmatically.