# NSNotificationCenter: Add observer but only if not registered to observe? Possible to query observing status for an object?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

Is there a way to see if an object is already an observer for a type of notification?

Currently, each `addObserver` call is paired with `removeObserver` to avoid duplicate observers, but is there a way to see if an object is already an observer before invoking `addObserver`?

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: CustomEvent, object: foo)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #("test"), name: CustomEvent, object: foo)
```

Comment: @ozgur ok please add as an answer so you can receive credit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there is not. Just like KVO, notification center doesn't provide an API that lets us check whether an object *(`self` in this case)* has already been registered as an observer or not.

Comment: thanks! awesome avatar :) btw do you also happen to know the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728704/delay-when-using-instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier-but-not-performseguewit

Answer (score 3):

You will have to yourself keep track using an bool variable and set it to "true" when you make an addObserver call and reset it when you call removeObserver.
Call addObserver again only when the bool is set to "false".

There is no other way to figure out if object is already an observer.