# How to determine what's running on main thread + slowing down UI?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I put in a new data loading feature in my app. It's meant to transfer and process the contents of a large database from the mobile device into the backend. In ever function I run in this pipeline, the entire contents of the function are inside a

```
dispatch_async
```

This dispatches to a non-main thread. I have also verified with logs that these are working. Every function along the pipeline is off the main thread. And yet I am experiencing UI freeze-up.

Questions:

1. What's the best way to figure out what is on the main thread and what it's doing/waiting for?
2. Is it ever possible to have non-main threads doing so much it actually impacts the main thread?

Comment: FYI - `dispatch_async` does not guarantee a background queue. It uses whatever queue you pass into it. Update your question with some relevant code.

Comment: @rmaddy - You're right, of course. We need more to go on. But in his defense, he did say that he was dispatching to a "non-main thread" [sic].

Comment: @Rob The OP does not say that "he" was dispatching to a "non-main thread". The OP states that `dispatch_async` dispatches to a "non-main thread". Hence my original comment.

Comment: @rmaddy - That's fine. But I'd be surprised if he's dispatching something slow and time consuming to the main queue and wondering why the app was not responsive. But your point is taken.

Comment: Bottom line is check if you've accidentally dispatched some heavy processor intensive operation in main thread.

Comment: Detailed how to use the profiler in this earlier thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728704/delay-when-using-instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier-but-not-performseguewit/36730253#36730253

Answer (score 8):

You should profile your app with Instruments. Time Profiler (make sure to use "Record Waiting Threads" option) can be useful, as is System Trace. For both, you might want to use the "Thread Strategy" view, [image], focusing on the main thread. There are a bunch of WWDC videos that describe various approaches, including the dated, yet still relevant, 2012 video [Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/211/). Also look for newer WWDC videos that reference "profiling" and "instruments".

Regarding non-main threads adversely affecting performance, it's generally negligible and you probably have something else going on. The only time it's a significant problem is when you're using a very old device that doesn't support multithreading.

By the way, are you 100% sure the main thread is really not being responsive? Or is it possibly that you're just not seeing UI updates being reflected in a timely manner? This can be a result of accidentally doing UI updates from the background thread rather than dispatching them back to the main queue.

If you want more concrete counsel, we need a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the performance problem. But in the abstract,

- make sure you don't have any time consuming operations on the main queue;
- make sure all UI updates are dispatched back to the main queue ... this includes *anything* that might trigger the update of a UIKit control;
- make sure your code doesn't "wait" for anything from the main thread (e.g. waiting for a semaphore, waiting for operations on an operation queue, waiting for dispatch group, etc.); and
- remember that not all asynchronous API will call their completion handlers on background queues (in fact, many dispatch it back to the main queue for the sake of ease of use), so if you're doing anything time consuming in a completion handler, confirm that it's actually getting run on a background thread or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Instruments for that, there are bunch of tools there you can use, such as Time Profiler, Allocations, System Usage etc. To open the tools use command+i in xcode or Xcode>Open Developer Tools>Instruments in the xcode menu.

Comment: Can you share how you analyse this UI operation with any item being updated on background thread.

Comment: can you please give more context for "this" UI operation?